# winapi - logonUser not supported

Tags: java, winapi, java-native-interface, authentication

i desperate.
my applications run as windows service, and it needs to create new regular process with different credentials.
it should run under win nt, xp, 7, etc.
because it runs as a service, i have to use the logonUser and CreateProcessAsUser win api functions (and not CreateProcessWithLogon).

on win 7 + win 2003 server it works perfect, but **on win xp i got error code 50 while invoking "logonUser" ("the request is not supported").**
i tried to play around with the local security policy, but it didn't work.

any suggestions?

(i invoke logonUser with default provider flag (0) and logon interactively (2)).

EDIT:
the problem is probably not windows xp. i run the same code on other win xp machine, and it worked. so, it is problably specific configuration on specific machine.
maybe the i changed some configurations while i was playing with previous problems (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898361/createprocessasuser-win-api-is-not-working-on-non-win7-platforms)

therefore, maybe my question should be: what configuration can effect the logonUser function, so the error message "The request is not supported" can be raised?

p.s.
i cant be sure that logonUser was successfully completed before, but i think it does.

Comment: Is this really Java? Or did you mis-tag?

Comment: actually, i uses java with JniWrapper... but, it is not related to the question.... thanks, pap.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CreateProcessAsUser win api is not working on non win7 platforms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898361/createprocessasuser-win-api-is-not-working-on-non-win7-platforms)

Comment: You already asked this question. Did you read the article that I linked to in a comment to that other question? The article explains why creating an interactive process from a service is a complicated task. Did you use the methods described there?

Comment: @yonatan - Not saying it's not relevant, just wanted to make sure. You should probably mention in the question that your are using JniWrapper.

Comment: @david i read every word in the links you gave me. this problem is little bit different. there, the problem was CreateProcessAsUser, here the problem is logonUser. i know that its wierd - bacause i should have ancountered the logon problem before i encountered this CreateProcessAsUser. i will edit the qeustion and explain this (and add some more new information)

Comment: I've something similar where I had to assign the privilege "Act as part of the operating system" in order to impersonate a user. [This page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457125.aspx) discusses it a bit. Not sure if that helps, but thought I'd share my similar experience.

Comment: @noelicus When you assigned this privilege did it not cross your mind that it was perhaps a rather draconian solution?!

Comment: It seemed strange. This was many years ago, I was young and on a computer without internet access with the simplicity of asking stack-overflow users etc! - don't judge me :) I'm not offering it as a solution but as a pointer to what allowed me to do it therefore shedding light on what may be required!!